# What is the correct way of using a pipe?

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

Heard so much about the wonders of pipes in R that I decided it is about time I learn how to use them.
I want to do an operation on a table, then add a column.It works as separate lines, but not when I try to use a pipe. Could someone please educate me on what is wrong with the way I am using the pipe?

```
modtable <- table - mean(table$blank[1:3]) %>%
    add_column(n=1)
```

Thanks!

The above returns the error:

`Error in if (nrow(df) != nrow(.data)) { : argument is of length zero`

Comment: What do you get when you do `table$blank`. If it is a `table` or `matrix` object, that won't work.  You need `table[, "blank"]` Also, in that case, I would first convert to data.frame i.e. `as.data.frame(table) %>% {. - mean(.$blank[1:3])} %>% add_column(n = 1)`

Answer (score 3):

We can wrap it in a `{}` to evaluate it as a block of code

```
{table - mean(table$blank[1:3]) }%>%
       add_column(n=1)
```

as the order or precedence of these operators (`%>%`) are lower than the `+`, `-` as showed in `?Syntax`

```
#:: ::: access variables in a namespace
#$ @    component / slot extraction
#[ [[   indexing
#^  exponentiation (right to left)
#- +    unary minus and plus    ####
#:  sequence operator
#%any%  special operators (including %% and %/%) #####
#* /    multiply, divide
```

---

In tidyverse, instead of doing this

```
library(dplyr)
table %>%
     mutate_all(~ . - mean(head(blank, 3))) %>%
     add_column(n = 1)
```

---

This can be reproducible with

```
data(mtcars)
head(mtcars) - mean(mtcars$mpg[1:3]) %>% 
  add_column(n = 1)
```

> Error in if (nrow(df) != nrow(.data)) { : argument is of length zero

if we create a block,

```
{head(mtcars) - mean(mtcars$mpg[1:3])} %>% 
     add_column(n = 1)
#                   mpg   cyl  disp    hp   drat      wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb n
#Mazda RX4         -0.6 -15.6 138.4  88.4 -17.70 -18.980 -5.14 -21.6 -20.6 -17.6 -17.6 1
#Mazda RX4 Wag     -0.6 -15.6 138.4  88.4 -17.70 -18.725 -4.58 -21.6 -20.6 -17.6 -17.6 1
#Datsun 710         1.2 -17.6  86.4  71.4 -17.75 -19.280 -2.99 -20.6 -20.6 -17.6 -20.6 1
#Hornet 4 Drive    -0.2 -15.6 236.4  88.4 -18.52 -18.385 -2.16 -20.6 -21.6 -18.6 -20.6 1
#Hornet Sportabout -2.9 -13.6 338.4 153.4 -18.45 -18.160 -4.58 -21.6 -21.6 -18.6 -19.6 1
#Valiant           -3.5 -15.6 203.4  83.4 -18.84 -18.140 -1.38 -20.6 -21.6 -18.6 -20.6 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the second option and it gives an error: Object 'blank' not found

Comment: @user10577351 if you don't have that column 'name', it won't work.  I showed a reproducible example that works

Comment: Thanks again. I do have that column name. It must be something to do with the fact that my data is a tibble. The only woy I got it to work is by `table %>%
     mutate_all(~ . - mean(head(table$blank, 3))) %>%
     add_column(n = 1)`

Comment: @user10577351. works for me `tmp <- as_tibble(head(mtcars));{tmp - mean(tmp$mpg[1:3])} %>% add_column(n = 1)`

Comment: @user10577351 may be it could be related to the package version